# ASP.NET MVC 4: jquery 500 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to AJAX.

I am trying to submit two arrays to a controller and then redirect to a new view. I am getting an error in my console: 'POST //.../League/AddPreRankList/ 500 (Internal Server Error)'

Here is my code,

JS

```
//handler for pre rank list submission
$("#SubmitPreRankList").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var PlayerIDS = new Array();
    $(".DraftList").each(function () {
        PlayerIDS.push(this.id);

    });

    var PreRanks = new Array();
    $(".DraftList").each(function () {
        PreRanks.push(($(this).index()));
    });

    //submit preranks
    $.ajax({
        url: '/League/AddPreRankList/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { PlayerIDS: PlayerIDS, PreRanks: PreRanks },
        success: function (response) {
            window.location = response.url;
        }

    });

});
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddPreRankList(int [] PlayerIDS, int [] PreRanks)
    {
        //Get the id from url
        string[] uri = Request.Url.Segments;
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(uri[3]);


        return Json(new { url = Url.Action("Home", "League", new { id = id }) });
    }
```

View

```
            <form id="SubmitPreRankList">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-9 columns">
                        <h2>My Pre-Rank List</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-3 columns">
                        <p>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-12 columns">
                        <ol id="UserPreRankList"></ol>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Are there any other details regarding the exception other than the 500? Do you see a stacktrace anywhere?

Comment: maybe the array is not int type? try `public JsonResult AddPreRankList(int? [] PlayerIDS, int? [] PreRanks)`

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, I am not sure where to look for other details regarding the exception. But there must be something very simple I'm missing because even when I pass no data, I will still get that error.

Comment: Adding ELMAH (http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) and/or Glimpse (http://getglimpse.com/) is going to be much more useful that just guessing - both have NuGet packages. Also, neither of your selectors match the markup you've included; where's the rest of the form?

Comment: Click on the url display in console then you will got the error that occurs in ajax request. Or trace the error in application_Error() in global.asax file

Comment: I created the list dynamically, I am able to output the correct data once I hit the submit button.

Comment: I am not sure if this helps, but this is what I get when I click on the url: Z.cors.a.crossDomain.send jquery.js:26
ab.extend.ajax jquery.js:25
(anonymous function) Site.js:61
ab.event.dispatch jquery.js:25
q.handle

Comment: you using google chrome? try to press keyboard f12 to bring out the debugging, point to the network, and fire again, and check the red color item, what is the error message, check this [link](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `JSON.stringify()`

```
data: JSON.stringify({ PlayerIDS: PlayerIDS, PreRanks: PreRanks })
```

also, you might want to use

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added that but am still getting 500 error

Comment: Try putting a break point on your Action in your Controller. Then you can inspect the values your are receiving. Also you might like to try [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see what you are sending to your application.